# Why my javascript doesn't work from the server

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just uploaded my website on a free host server but it doesn't work properly. I don't know why...

can you help me please ?

see the link : 
    https://electrophotonique.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: because you read the element before it exists on the page....

Comment: And you have tons of 404 errors

Comment: sorry but I don't understand. I'm not a webmaster...

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine but you just need to put your scripts at the end of your code  before the `</body>`  tag Like this :

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style2.css">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="IMAGES/PNG/favicon.png">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Electrophotonique Ingenierie</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   </head>
   <body>

       <!-- YOUR CODE - START -->

         .....

       <!-- YOUR CODE - END -->


      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/sticky_navbar.js"></script>
      <script src="js/button.js"></script>
      <script src="js/index.js"></script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually it was like that. I change the place of the scripts for test. It stil doesn't work ...

Comment: Your current js folder name is **JS** so you need to  rename it